# VS terminal just outputting two directories?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am writing a small script to create an Excel workbook with new sheets.
But every time I try and run it the terminal window opens and just shows:

```
& "C:/Program Files/Python39/python.exe" "c:/Users/Jerome/Desktop/VS Code Projects/Python/Excel workbook/excel_sheet.py"
```

I am not sure what this means?

```
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

# This creates the workbook
wb = Workbook()

# the add_sheet() method is used to create a sheet
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

sheet1.write(1, 0, "Chris Smith")

# this saves the workbook
wb.save('new-sheet.xlsx')
```

Comment: How are you running the script?  By double-clicking an icon in windows?

Comment: There is no print function

Comment: Try running it manually - python3 <file_path>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error. It is a command that runs your code with python interpreter. For example if you put a `print('end')` at the end of your code you can see the print result after this line.

I assume you run the code by clicking on the top right run button in vscode or some other editors. They write this command in the terminal to run your code with python. It is not an error.

`"C:/Program Files/Python39/python.exe"` this part is the path to python exe file. and `"c:/Users/Jerome/Desktop/VS Code Projects/Python/Excel workbook/excel_sheet.py"` is the path to the file of your code.

When you run this code open the folder your code exists in. You have to see a new file named `new-sheet.xlsx` been created. (also I ran your code everything is ok).

If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But what's the difference between PowerShell in the terminal and the little window that says Python at the bottom?

Comment: @JeromeJohn Do you mean `command prompt` in vscode by saying "the little window that says python at the bottom"? I don't understand which window you are talking about.

Comment: @JeromeJohn In vs code you can choose between some terminal windows like PowerShell and Command Prompt. I always use CommandPrompt but you can use PowerShell. PowerShell is somehow a more advanced version of cmd but with some specific attributes. I prefer cmd.

Comment: On the bottom half of the screen it says "Terminal" and then it says "Python" to the right.

I guess what I am asking is do you only need Powershell to view the output of my Python files?

Comment: Click on the python terminal. Is it in python shell?

Comment: Yes it looks like it.

Comment: When you type `python` in terminal it runs `python shell`. When vscode sees you are running python shell it changes the `cmd` name to `python`.

Comment: Okay stupid question: as far as changing directories to run my code should that be done in PowerShell or Python shell?

Comment: It can be in powershell or cmd but not in python shell. Python shell is just for running simple python code. It is not for changing directories. I suggest you use CMD (command prompt).

Comment: Can CMD run both Python scripts and change directories?

Comment: yes there is no difference. You can type `cd somedirectory` to change directory or type `python myfile.py` to run python file.

Comment: So I when I click the play button (top right) for my Python script it defaults to the Python shell. I'd like it to open in CMD. Do you know how to change that? Sorry to bug you with so many questions!

Comment: No problem my friend. Please accept my answer as accepted answer as it answered your question. I am going to search my vscode setting to send you the exact setting you need to add to make it open in the cmd.

Comment: In vscode setting (setting.json) there is a line like this you have to change that to this: `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",`. This says that it should open it in cmd.